# Is there a way to release mysql connections?

Tags: php, mysql, unix, mysqli

The thing is I have a cronjob that repeats itself every 2min & calls a php script which does some mysql query.. now that thing is making mysql very busy which in the process is consuming too much memory.. my allocated RAM is 2GB.. it's getting used in like 4hours or so then in couple of hours the extra VSwap of 2GB is getting used. then it simply crashes giving `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused`

I am not exactly sure what is wrong.. I know a cron that calls a mysql query every 2min might be a bad call.. but I donno how to manage it otherwise.. so I need a solution. I am using a CentOS 6.6 Server

Comment: A mysql query every 2 minutes shouldn't be a problem, could you share your php script?

Comment: seems to be some script making connections in a loop

Comment: close the mysql connection using mysqli_close(connection) or increase number of connection in mysql

Comment: Use the [mysqli::close](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) function to close the connection when your job is finished with it. I suspect that that is not really your problem though as connections are closed when PHP programs exit. Could your job being running more than 2 minutes resulting in multiple connections that accumulate over time?

Comment: DO NOT INCREASE THE NUMBER OF CONNECTIONS MYSQL WILL ALLOW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Codeigniter 3. There were some persistent connections. I had set the `pconnect` to `FALSE`. but that did not work so I added a `destructor` to close the connection.

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
}
```

That sorted it. Thanks to all for your responses. I thought it was some server issue and I did not provide enough information in the question. It was stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Change the frequency to 20 minutes to give some time to determine what is really going on rather than facing a flurry of activity every 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

What's going wrong is that your system is mis-configured. On a Linux system, going into swap is really bad - it doesn't just result a slowdown due to the time taken to page out/page back in, you also lose your VFS cache, and as the load goes up, the processes are pre-empted instead of being allowed to yield.

> then it simply crashes giving

That seems rather unlikely. It's more likely that the OOM killer is harvesting the process.

Configuring your system correctly will take a lot of time and knowledge, but you should start by installing [mysqltuner.pl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) and reconfiguring your MySQL instance to fit into the available RAM.

> that repeats itself every 2min

That's not good. And its compounding the paging issue leading to a race condition. So as a matter of some priority you should be configuring this to fail if another instance is active (e.g. using lock files). Note that this is a quick fix. You should be designing your system so such frequent batch operations are not required.